# Why some of my queries are really long (above 5000 ms) on MySQL server?

Tags: c#, mysql, npoco

I have a `C#` application using `NPoco` that is doing many queries on a `MySQL` server (`version 5.6.17`).

The usual time for these queries is between a couple of `ms` and `40 ms`.

However sometimes it seems that some queries are taking the usual time plus `5000 ms` and I absolutely don’t understand why (e.g. `5021 ms`). It is also always the queries that are already the most heavy ones that have this behavior (i.e. the queries that takes usually around `40 ms`).

(I've installed the `MySQL` server with the `WAMP` package (http://www.wampserver.com/) because I also needed the `Apache` server and the `PHP` server.)

Do you have an idea where I should look to fix this annoying problem?

Comment: did you try repeating the queries and profile out specific type of queries which take such long time ?

Comment: I've measured the time from my C# application. Maybe there is a better way provided by MySQL itself, but I don't know it...

Comment: If you know the queries that take so long you can throw them into mysql workbench and change the SELECT into a [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html). You might have to place some additional [indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) in your database to speed things up. You might also want to check your application in how it handles connections. If you leave them open you might end up with a timed out one. Maybe a exception makes your application reconnect, but timeouts always take a long time (obviously as you have to wait)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I'll try the EXPLAIN to see what it  says. I'm also keeping one connection open per thread in my application, do you think that it can be the cause of my problem?

Comment: @laurentIsRunning: That depends on how long the thread is running and if the thread is on 'standby' or not. In general a connection is only allowed to be open and idle for a x amount of time (this is defined in your database settings). Once that time expires the connection is closed by the server. If your application then tries to use that connection it will eventually end in a timeout exception. Its generally good practice to close a connection as soon as possible. A Using block is a nice trick for this [using example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection)